# date and time format in angular

Tags: java, angular

When storing my record in to the database I am using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to save the createdon column.
To retrieve that timestamp I am using `import java.sql.Timestamp;`

**DTO: -**

```
private Timestamp createdon;
```

In my database the timestamp is `2020-08-06 17:28:00.439`

my DTO is returning Timestamp as `2020-08-06T11:58:00.439+0000`, How can I display time as `06/08/2020 hours:minutes:seconds`

Comment: Your DTO ist returning a different time? Why do you use `java.sql.Timestamp` when there are `java.time.Instant`, `java.time.OffsetDateTime` and `java.time.ZonedDateTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a date filter:

```
{{createdon | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use date pipe of angular in your html

```
{{ yourDateValue | date:'M/d/yy, h:mm:ss' }}
```

For more please refer [Angular DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)